# VLOOKUP or/and MATCH Function

Tags: excel, function, match, vlookup

I have two spreadsheets:

The first spreadsheet consists of two columns: App Codes (4 digit codes) and the specific App Name that comes with the App Code. There are about 5300 App Codes & App Names.

The second spreadsheet consists of one column: App Codes and for this one there are only 4900 App Codes.

Essentially I'm trying to find out which 400 App Codes are missing. I'm wondering if it's possible to put the three columns next to each other and when there arent two app codes for the cell to say "N/A" (the 400 App Codes that are missing).

I've been reading up on Vlookup and Match functions but don't quite understand how to do it in this real life concept. I'm hoping someone can walk me through steps on how to make this possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that spreadsheet 2 is called Sheet2 and let's assume both spreadsheets have header names in the first row (the codes and names hence start as from row 2 downwards).

You can use a `VLOOKUP` like this in cell C2 of the first spreadsheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet2!A:A, 1, FALSE)
```

And copy/paste (or fill down) this formula till the end of the data table.

The formula actually pulls matching App Codes from spreadsheet 2 so that if there's no corresponding App Code from spreadsheet 2, you will get `#N/A`

If you want to use `MATCH`, it's like that:

```
=MATCH(A2, Sheet2!A:A, 0)
```

In contrast to `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH` will return the row number in which it has found the match instead of the value of that cell, but will still return `#N/A` if it cannot find a match.

---

EDIT: Due to spaces in lookup_table, you have two options and since you seem to prefer the MATCH method, I'll give the two options for this:

1)

```
=MATCH(A2, TRIM(Sheet2!A:A), 0)
```

This is an array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work instead of simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The array formula is slower than a usual formula.

2)

```
=MATCH("*"&A2&"*", Sheet2!A:A, 0)
```

This one is a usual formula, but works if you're sure that there's no overlapping App Code, and by that, I mean something like if you have both an App Code '42' and '420' in the same range, it won't work as intended. It's substantially faster than the array formula above however.

---

EDIT2: Turns out the data is a real mess and some of the values have been converted to dates, others to scientific notation. I resorted to:

```
=MATCH(TRIM(A2), TRIM(Sheet2!A:A), 0)
```

There are still App Codes in the lookup table that have been disformed (presumably through mishandling of the data), but those will require manual editing to fix. Stuff like `2.00E+00` could be an AppCode in the form `2E00`.

---

EdIT3: [It's getting long :)]

If you want to get a 3rd column with the corresponding App Name you just fetched, use `VLOOKUP` (the formula is as per the file you sent me):

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2),TRIM(Sheet1!A:B),2,0)
```

Again, this is an array formula, so use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make it work instead of simply <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Hi Jerry, the match function is working perfectly when the app code consists of four numeric values.  But for the app codes that are alpha numeric (e.g. 11RT) it shows N/A for all of them.  And N/A is impossible as I see 11RT in Sheet2. Is there a way we can fix this?

Comment: @hanijamal MATCH works for both numeric and text values. Could there be extra spaces in either the values of your two spreadsheets?

Comment: Yes there are 2 leading spaces in Sheet 2 for all entries (e.g. "  9J00".  Is there any way we can trim it to just four characters all at once instead of going through row by row?

Comment: I've trimmed the spaces in Sheet 2 now the rows are being generated for some of the alpha numeric codes but not all of them? Do you know why this occurring?

Comment: do you have a couple of minutes.  Is it possible for you to set up a chat I can send you the data on there it will only take a few moments of your time and I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm not quite sure how to set up a chat on here.

Comment: Apparently I don't have enough reputation to chat.. Is it possible for you to provide an e-mail and you can delete your comment with the e-mail as soon as I've sent it to you?

Comment: Thanks again, I've just sent you the e-mail can you confirm that you can open the excel?

Comment: @hanijamal Okay, I think most of the issues are solved. There's only the App Codes in the first table that has some dates and scientific numbers as codes which I guess appeared after some mishandling of the data. I sent it back to you and updated my answer here.

Comment: Sorry one last question.  Sheet 2 you have the App Code and the Missing Code Column.  Is there a way I can have a third column with the designated App Name that comes with the Code?  Otherwise I'll still have to flip back and forth between the Sheets to find out which row for all 5000 of them.  If you could just edit your answer so I can try it out.  Thanks again

Comment: @hanijamal Okay, added formula.

Comment: It's showing #NUM1.. is it possible for you to e-mail it to me with the app names as the third column? It will only take a moment. Promise this is the last thing! Thanks again Jerry you've actually helped me a great deal.